winotify notification keeps on showing on callback
I'm trying to show windows notification using winotify. My problem is it keeps on showing when I click the button that has a callback to open a web browser. Also is there a way to not show the command prompt when clicking the button?
from winotify import Notification, audio, Notifier, Registry
import webbrowser
import json

registry = Registry(app_id="myapp", script_path=__file__)
notifier = Notifier(registry)


class Toast:

    def __init__(self):
        self.notify()

    @notifier.register_callback
    def toast_callback():
        webbrowser.open('http://google.co.kr', new=2)

        return json.dumps({'message': 'link has been clicked'})

    def notify(self):
        toast = Notification(app_id="308046B0AF4A39CB", title="Message Title",
                             msg="Hellow World",
                             duration="short"
                             )

        toast.set_audio(audio.Reminder, loop=False)

        toast.add_actions(label="Button text",
                          launch=notifier.callback_to_url(self.toast_callback))
        toast.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    notifier.start()
    myapp = Toast()

